# Does ubuntu 18.04 delete files without my consent?

Tags: python, delete, postgresql

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 for development but it's giving me countless frustrations. First I had to reinstall `postgres` because, for whatever reason, I logged in and it wasn't working. Today I log in and my python virtual environment isn't working - turns out the `bin` directory is somehow lost! I did what anyone would do: `rm -r venv`, create a new venv, and reinstall packages. Just as I thought all was done, ran into errors and figured my `.env` file had been deleted! As if all that wasn't enough, I tried `ssh-ing` into different servers and I'd be prompted for a password yet I have my public key copied to all of them already - which worked as expected previously!

TH! Has anyone else faced such issues? It's driving me crazy!!!

Comment: Are you, by chance, running from a live USB/boot instance which does not persist between reboots?

Comment: @ckwagaba I recommend you **[edit]** with more info--at minimum, whether or not you're using a live environment [as Minty described](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167994/does-ubuntu-18-04-delete-files-without-my-consent#comment1948917_1167994), but also more detailed descriptions. This really does sound like you're using a live environment and not saving your data to any actual disk. But you said you *installed* 18.04. Although [that post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1168001) is accurate, it doesn't explain what you've observed. If you **[edit]**, this will be reviewed for possible reopening.

Answer (score 2):

No, Ubuntu does not "delete files without your  consent".